# Twilio proxy + click to call

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm trying to combo the concepts found [here (make a voice call with proxy)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/quickstart#make-a-voice-call) and [here (click to call)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call) but I'm running into a bit of a mental hurdle in that it seems to initialize a proxy call, you need to call a number. From the docs:

> If your Twilio Phone Numbers are voice capable, you're now ready for a proxied voice conversation. Following the names from the previous steps, get Alice to make a call to her Proxy Identifier number. Twilio's Proxy service will then make a call from Bob's Proxy Number to his real number and connect the two calls.

What I'd like to do is have Alice click a button on her desktop, have the Proxy Identifier Number call her, then let Twilio's proxy make the call from Bob's proxy number to his real number and the two of them could chat.

Is there a way to trigger the call from the Proxy Identifier number to Alice?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Twilio REST API Calls Resource to initially trigger the call to connect the parties, using each participants proxy number as the respective CallerID. When they call or SMS each other back, the proxy session will be active.

[Making Calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls)

[TwiML™ Voice:  - Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial)

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks for the comment here, but we are struggling to get this to work. The calls both remain on hold forever playing the demo music. Our process is:

1. Create proxy session
2. Add both participants to the session
3. Create call from proxy number one to participant one
4. Create call from proxy number two to participant two